# How to fix "Can't use $set" error on Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose with the given schema:

```
const StockSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
  "materialDefinition_id": {
    "type": "ObjectId",
    "ref": "MaterialDefinition",
    "required": true
  },
  "quantity": {
    "type": "Number",
    "required": true
  },
  "committedOrder_id": {
    "type": "ObjectId",
    "ref": "Order"
  },
  "committedOrderItemIndex": {
    "type": "Number"
  },
  "detachedOrder_id": {
    "type": "ObjectId",
    "ref": "Order"
  },
  "detachedOrderItemIndex": {
    "type": "Number"
  },
  "deletedAt": {
    "type": "Number"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "type": "Number"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "type": "Number"
  }
});
```

I'm getting error in the following transaction:

```
try {
    await StockModel.update(
        {
            $or: [
                { committedOrder_id: purchaseOrder._id },
                { detachedOrder_id: purchaseOrder._id }
            ]
        },
        {
            $set: {
                committedOrder_id: null,
                committedOrderItemIndex: null,
                detachedOrder_id: null,
                detachedOrderItemIndex: null
            }
        }
    );
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error updating stock!");
    console.log(err);
}
```

Error:

```
Error updating stock!
Error: Can't use $set
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1368:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1347:17)
    at cast (/Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:288:39)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (/Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4644:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (/Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1842:10)
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2097:8)
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (/Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:16:8)
    at /Users/workspace/dev/app/dev/node_modules/kareem/index.js:369:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: What I think is that we can't set null value on the field which has ObectId as type.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, `update` is executed on a document object, see [document.prototype.update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update)

You can try this instead:

```
await StockModel.findOneAndUpdate({
    $where: { $or: [{ committedOrder_id: purchaseOrder._id }, { detachedOrder_id: purchaseOrder._id }] },
    $set: {
        committedOrder_id: null,
        committedOrderItemIndex: null,
        detachedOrder_id: null,
        detachedOrderItemIndex: null
    }
});
```